# Traffic shaping bandwidth and latency based on IP

Tags: traffic-shaping

I am aware of how to shape latency and bandwidth separately. For bandwidth, I can do

```
wondershaper etho0 100 100
```

for latency I can run

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 200ms
```

However, I need to restrict shaping to specific IP connections and I need to shape latency and bandwidth simultaneously.

How can I do this?

Comment: tc can do both latency and bandwidth. The lines `tc qdisc add dev wlan0 root handle 1:0 htb default 10` and 
`tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1:0 classid 1:10 htb rate 64kbps ceil 64kbps prio 0` would shape everyone to 64kbps

Comment: However, I need to restrict shaping to only certain IPs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tc to shape bandwidth like so

This class will shape certain addresses to a certain speed.
We also need to setup a filter so that any packets marked as such go through this rule

`tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:5 htb rate 256kbps ceil 256kbps prio 1

tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1:0 prio 1 handle 5 fw flowid 1:5`

Once that class is setup, you need to setup iptables to mark the specific packets you want to shape.

Next, create the mangle table that's needed.

`iptables -t mangle -N shaper-out

iptables -t mangle -N shaper-in`

`iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -i eth0 -j shaper-in

iptables -t mangle -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j shaper-out`

Next setup the marks that we need to shape certain IP addresses. mark 5 is the one that is shaped to 256.
`iptables -t mangle -A shaper-out -s 10.0.0.5 -j MARK --set-mark 5

iptables -t mangle -A shaper-in -d 10.0.0.5 -j MARK --set-mark 5`

That should shape 10.0.0.5 to 256kbps.

Reference (my blog) - http://sirlagz.net/2013/01/27/how-to-turn-the-raspberry-pi-into-a-shaping-wifi-router/